# Class Label not found sklearn error

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

Error:

```
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found
warning: class label 1 specified in weight is not found


def BaggingClassifierSVM(X_train,y):
    n_estimators = 10
    subsample_train=2000
    X_train=X_train[::subsample_train,:]
    y=y[::subsample_train,:]
    clf = OneVsRestClassifier(BaggingClassifier(SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True, class_weight='auto'), max_samples=1.0 / n_estimators, n_estimators=n_estimators))
    clf.fit(X_train,y)
    return clf
```

Don't understand the error, didn't get while learn `linearSVC`. And also get it while BAggingClassifier on other datasets like iris. Thanks.

Edit:

Dataset->
https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B16PrXUjs69zfmpMYk1mcnlfWDlTdjBUUWFHaHNrT2ZQY2RJNUVKbUVIRDJXMHU0R1h5R0k&usp=sharing

use`np.load(<filepath>)`

Comment: Please elucidate on downvote. It will help me. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide code with dataset?

Comment: @Olologin I have added the dataset in the question. Sorry it is a bit large that's why I didn't upload at the start.

Answer (score 2):

As I found out - it is bug in sklearn SVM implementation, seems that it appears only when used together with Bagging. To reproduce it you just need to pass the sample_weights parameter into fit method, where weights of samples of some class entirely zeroed. That's what implicitly happening when Bagging algorithm randomly zeroes sample_weights to create subsets for basic estimators. It tends to exclude most of the classes, and in case with this SVM implementation it leads to bug.

I'll report this bug. Instead of using SVM you can use another basic estimator, or use another ensemble method instead of bagging, it may help you.

Comment: Please post a link to the bug report. I think it hasn't been fixed yet.

Comment: This still hasn't been fixed.

Comment: This still havent been fixed - sitting with the exact same bug